# Do Chrome extensions save cookies?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies

I want my extension to be able to get and save the cookies of a specific website in its storage and render the user profile page using those cookies when clicked on the extension and in case user has already logged into that website for example using a tab. I know I can get the cookies of a website using chrome.cookies.get() but I don't know how to save them as my extensions cookies! Do Chrome extensions even store cookies?
Can you please help me about this?

Comment: You could always just serialize them and save them in the extension storage?

Comment: Would you please provide some topics or even links to help me understand it?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Note that any data you want to store in the chrome storage will be serialized (as if you had done `JSON.stringify(data)`).